# Python MariaDB has no attribute 'Connection'

Tags: python, mariadb, connection, connector

I installed python3, pip3, and the mariadb-module on my Ubuntu machine but i cannot start my programm because I am getting the error "AttributeError: module 'mariadb' has no attribute 'Connection'".

On my Window-Machine everything works fine and I cannot find the issue.

Plz help

Best regards,
Maxi

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection is not supposed to be capitalized:

https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/usage.html#connecting

Answer (score 0):

Creating Connection object is only available in MariaDB Connector/C 1.1 which is currently alpha:

```
>>> import mariadb
>>> c=mariadb.Connection(db="test")
>>> c.database
'test'
```

For version 1.0.x you will obtain Connection object via connect() method.

```
>>> import mariadb
>>> c=mariadb.connect(db="test")
>>> c.database
'test'
```